# unable to convert ssh-add in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I want to convert a shell script to a docker file but I am not sure what is wrong with my script conversion. would you mind checking it?

```
FROM alpine:3.4

ENV MY_PARAM noninteractive
ENV MYUSER noninteractive
ENV MYSERVER noninteractive
ENV SSH_PRIVATE_KEY noninteractive

RUN eval $(ssh-agent -s)
RUN ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
RUN set -eux
RUN params=()
RUN params+=("$MY_PARAM")
RUN echo "${params[@]}"
RUN ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $MYUSER@$MYSERVER "/bin/bash -s" < myscript.sh "${params[@]}"
```

I am getting below error now

> Step 28/43 : RUN ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
> ---> Running in 57a6ac3ccd24

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected The command '/bin/sh -c ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")' returned a non-zero code: 2

Also, take note that during the build I am not passing any env and I want to send variables during the run time not during the build.

Comment: The line you quote in the error isn't [standard Bourne shell syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18).  Even if it does run correctly, your ssh key will be accessible in clear text in `docker inspect` output and in the container filesystem.  I'd revisit this section of your Docker setup – I'd be a little surprised to see a Dockerfile, intended to produce a reproducible image, making an outbound ssh call to a specific host to run an imperative command.

Comment: I want to pass the parameter during runtime and we just run this docker to deploy a docker on a server and then it will be removed. is using RUN a correct command or I should use CMD?

Comment: That sounds like you want to write a shell script that runs on the host, where it can directly use the `ssh-agent` from the desktop environment.  That will be much easier than trying to securely pass the credentials into a container.